# Speed up reading/hashing millions of files/images

Tags: python, hash, io

I have directories containing 100K - 1 million images. I'm going to create a hash for each image so that I can, in the future, find an exact match based on these hashes. My current approach is:

```py
def hash_test(images):      # images is a list of image paths
    hashes = []
    for image in images:
        with open(folder + image, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
           hashes.append(hashlib.sha256(f.read()).hexdigest())
           # hashes.append(CityHash128(f.read()))
    return hashes
```

```
31%|███       | 102193/334887 [00:04<42:15, 112.02it/s]
```

Of what I can tell from my experiments, the `file.read()` operation is my bottleneck, which means that I am I/O bound. This is also confirmed by checking `iotop` . I am reading from a HDD. I have read about memory-mapped reading, but couldn't get my head around whether it was applicable in this situation or not.

My question is: is there a way to optimize this reading operation?

Comment: You should consider trying asyncio or a thread pool if you are io bound

Comment: Why did you turn buffering off (`buffering=0`)?

Comment: How come pooling will help if only one thread at a time can read from disk? Buffering is turn off for no particular reason. Just some left over after a copy-paste operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to parallelise your hash computation code like below. However, the performance depends upon how much parallel IO requests the disk can handle and also on how many cores does your CPU have. But, you can try.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# This function will return hashes as list
# Will wait for all parallel hash computation to complete

def parallel_hash(images):
    with Pool(5) as pool:
        return pool.map(hash_test, images)

def hash_test(image):      # images is a list of image paths
    with open(folder + image, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
        return hashlib.sha256(f.read()).hexdigest()
        # hashes.append(CityHash128(f.read()))

parallel_hash(images)
```

Comment: I thought parallelizing code when IO bound didn't do much and moving the read-head to do so was a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that the problem has to do with the number of files in a directory. Some file systems experience severely degraded performance when you get many thousands of files in a single directory. If you have 100K or more files in a single directory, it takes significant time for the file system just to *find* the file before opening and reading it.

That said, let's think about this a bit. If I'm reading your output correctly, your program completed approximately 102K out of 335K files in four hours and 42 minutes. In round numbers, that's about 6 files per second. So it'll take about 15.5 hours to do all 335K files.

If this is a one-time task, then just set it up to run overnight, and it'll be done when you get back to work in the morning. If you have to index a million files, start the process on Friday night and it'll be done when you get into the office on Monday.

If it's not a one-time task, then you have other problems . . .

Comment: The files are not all in a single directory, rather a tree structure where each "leaf-folder" has about 10K images. Not sure if this still would be of importance? The time stamp is actually in min:sec. It took 4s to do the first 31% because of the CPU cache, and in total ~50 min for all ~300K images. So not a big deal.

Comment: 10K images in a single folder was definitely a problem for NTFS a while back. Don't know if it still is. But if you can do 300K images in less than an hour, and it's a one-time (or at least infrequent) task, then you're probably just fine. If it's fast enough, leave it alone. :)